# I want to read file which is stored in my D: drive using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

My uploaded file is stored in

`D:\eclipseworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\DatasetFileUpload\myNewFolder`

Now I want to read a file which is stored in above location using ajax but when I gave that complete path to ajax URL it shows me an error.

Comment: You cannot access data through the file system. You need to place that file in a folder (either physical or virtual) that is accessible to the web server and then use that path instead.

Comment: can you please help me with the code

Comment: There's no code to write. You just need to setup your server correctly in the manner I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call is only possible across the same server or remote server with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" permission.

You need to host that file on any sever and call that file through AJAX.